# Find what change occured when the Changed event is fired in a FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher, .net-4.0

I am using a `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor changes to files.

MSDN documentation says that if **`Changed`** is passed for the `ChangeType` in the `FileSystemEventArgs` parameter, it indicated *"The change of a file or folder. The types of changes include: changes to size, attributes, security settings, last write, and last access time."*

Is there a way to find out *which* one of those changed? For example, last access can alone change without change to size. I want to find that out. How can I do it?

**P.S.** Of course if I record all the attributes that I care about every time `Changed` event is fired, and then compared them, I can find out what changed. But is there an easier way.. like being notified through some event or reading a property of some object? :D

Comment: Are you aware of the [limited buffer size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.internalbuffersize.aspx#remarksToggle) ? If many changes happen, details are lost.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it. I read about it in MSDN docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter to filter events based on what happened. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter.aspx#Y333)